# Is there a general form for $y^{(n)}=y$?

Tags: calculus

For $y' =y$ we get $y = c_1 e^x$.

For $y'' = y$ we get $y = c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$.

Is there a general solution for the $n\text{th}$ derivative of y?

Comment: Hint. Yes. You use the (complex) roots of $x^n -1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We look for solutions of the type $e^{rx}$.  Thus, we must have $r^n=1$.  So, the general solution can be written

$$y(x)=\sum_{m=1}^n c_me^{r_mx}$$

where $r_m=e^{i2\pi m/n}$ for $m=1,\dots,n$.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)) formed by this ODE.  Given $y^{(n)} = y$, the characteristic equation is $z^n - 1 =0$, which means we are looking for the $n$-th [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

We can determine these roots by substituting $z = e^{i\theta}$ and finding $n$ such that:

$$e^{i\theta n} = 1$$

This is true whenever $\theta n$ is a multiple of $2\pi$.  Thus, we have $n$ options for $\theta$:

$$\theta = 0, \frac{2\pi}{n}, \frac{4\pi}{n}, \dots, \frac{2\pi(n-1)}{n}$$

So, the solutions to the characteristic are the $n$th roots of unity:
$$z_0 = e^{0},\; z_1 = e^{2\pi i/n},\; z_2 = e^{4\pi i/n},\dots,\; z_{n-1} =  e^{2\pi(n-1) i/n}$$

Returning to the method of characteristic equations, the solution must have the form:
\begin{align*}
  y &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k e^{z_k x}\\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k \exp\left(xe^{i 2\pi k/n}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Going off of the other answer (Dr MV's), here's what it looks like without complex numbers:

Note that $r_m = e^{i2 \pi m/n} = \cos(2 \pi m/n) + i \sin (2 \pi m/n) := a_m + ib_m$.  By reorganizing the sum, we find
$$
y = \sum_{m=1}^{\lceil n/2-1 \rceil} e^{a_m\,x}[c_{1,m} \cos(b_m x) + c_{2,m} \sin(b_m x)] + d_1 e^x + \overbrace{d_2 e^{-x}}^{\text{ if $n$ is even}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

This covers the general case $y^{(n)} = ky$ and explains discrepancies with Wolfram Alpha.

We forget the $k$ for now and consider

$$ y^{(n)} = y $$

Which functions satisfy this? Suppose $u$ is a complex number such that $u^n =1$ (I'm not sure if you are aware but these are called [complex roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) and have the form $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ one can use some simple algebra to verify that $(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}})^n = e^{2\pi i} = 1$) . Then

$$ (e^{ux})' = ue^{ux} \\ (e^{ux})'' = u^2e^{ux} \\ \vdots \\ (e^{ux})^{(n)} = u^n e^{ux} = e^{ux} $$

So $e^{ux}$ would be a solution to $ y^{(n)} = y $ .There is a theorem that there are in general $n$ such distinct complex roots of unity of degree $n$ and they are given by $e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}$ where $k = 1 .. n $  (in fact they consist of $n$ equally spaced points around the unit circle and include the point $z=1$)

So we have then that the general solution looks like

$$ y = C_1 e^{e^\frac{2\pi i}{n} x} + C_2 e^{e^\frac{4\pi i}{n} x} + C_3 e^{e^\frac{6\pi i}{n} x}  +  ... + e^{e^\frac{2n\pi i}{n} x} $$

For the general problem with $k$ a positive real this becomes

$$ y = C_1 e^{e^\frac{2\pi i}{n} k^{\frac{1}{n}} x} + C_2 e^{e^\frac{4\pi i}{n} k^{\frac{1}{n}} x} + C_3 e^{e^\frac{6\pi i}{n} k^{\frac{1}{n}} x}  +  ... + e^{e^\frac{2n\pi i}{n} k^{\frac{1}{n}} x} $$

(You should be able to prove this if you understood everything up to this point, if not I can go over it)

It's easy to check now that setting $n=1$ and $n=2$ recovers the results you found because $k = k^1 = k^{\frac{1}{1}} $ and  $ \sqrt{k} = k^{\frac{1}{2}} $ respectively

Now Wolfram Alpha appears to express the answer in terms of sine and cosine. You might wonder why this is happening. There is actually a famous theorem called [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) which states:

$$ e^{ix} = cos(x) + i \sin(x) $$

Now these complex roots of unity we have been looking at $u_{n,l} = e^{\frac{2\pi i l}{n}}$ can be expressed in cartesian coordinates as $$ u_{n,l} = e^{\frac{2\pi i l}{n}} = \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right) + i \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right) $$

So then

$$ e^{u_{n,l}k^{\frac{1}{n}} x} = e^{\left(\cos\left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right) + i \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right)  \right)k^{\frac{1}{n}} x } $$

And now we can use some basic algebra to factor this:

$$ e^{u_{n,l}k^{\frac{1}{n}} x} = e^{\cos \left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right) k^{\frac{1}{n}}x}e^{i \sin\left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right) k^{\frac{1}{n}}x}  $$

And now that $e^{i \sin\left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right) k^{\frac{1}{n}}x} $ can be treated with Euler's formula to finally yield:

$$  e^{u_{n,l}k^{\frac{1}{n}} x} = e^{\cos \left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} k^{\frac{1}{n}} x \right)} \left( \cos \left( \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right) k^{\frac{1}{n}}x \right) + i \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac{2 \pi i l}{n} \right)  k^{\frac{1}{n}}x \right) \right)    $$

And that is the general pattern wolfram alpha is showing (with further simplifications, those inner sines and cosines turn into nice algebraic numbers).

See for example: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27%27+%3D+3y

Where every term is multiplied by $e^{a_n * 3^{\frac{1}{3}x}}$ where $a_n = 1, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}$ and the three cubic roots of unity are $1, \frac{-1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$